# Django - Retornar estatus del método save() de un modelo

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo la necesidad de obtener el estatus del método `save()` de un modelo, específicamente necesito saber si al guardar el registro en base de dato, este fue insertado o actualizado correctamente.

¿Es posible que luego de guardar un objeto `obj.save()` se pueda obtener el estatus de la operación?

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: En primer lugar necesitaría un ejemplo del código para poder ayudarte, también saber con que estás trabajando, si es con Django, si es una API, etc.

Comment: Si, sería bueno saber que es lo que necesitas saber con exactitud, sin embargo, puedo decirte que [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) puedes encontrar bastante información acerca de las señales, y quizás esto te ayude a resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Django si no guarda correctamente el registro te devuelve una excepción te basta con meterlo dentro de un try

```
 try: 
     .....
     object.save()
 except:
     print("no se guardo correctamente")
```

Answer (score 0):

para mostrar un mensaje al guardar un model puedes usar la siguiente guia:
[mensaje personalizado django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548325/django-customizing-the-message-after-a-successful-form-save?rq=1)
**en tu vista podrias usar algo asi:**

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Data insertada correctamente.')
```

**en el template**

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**suerte !!**